# Write to gzipped fasta file in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5, biopython

I have just migrated all modules in my tool from python 2 to python 3. I run into a problem I just could not solve - I don't know how to write to gzipped fasta file.

```
with gzip.open("sample.fasta.gz", "w") as file:
    print("writing...")
    for oid, seq in temp_data.items():
        # prepare row
        row = SeqRecord(Seq(seq), id=str(oid), description=temp_tax[oid])
        SeqIO.write(row, file, "fasta")
```

This code works in python 2 but it does not work in python 3, it raises:

> TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

How should I fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`gzip.open` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open), unlike the regular `open` function, defaults to binary mode, not text mode. You have to explicitly pass a `t` as part of the mode string to open in text mode (which accepts/expects `str`):

```
with gzip.open("sample.fasta.gz", "wt") as file:
```

To avoid line ending conversion, you may also want to [pass `newline=''`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) (the empty string) so that, on a system like Windows, it doesn't convert `\n` to `\r\n` when it writes.

Comment: I totally forgot about `t` option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the string which is returned from `SeqRecord` to a `bytes` object.

```
byte_row = record.format('').encode()
```

[`record.format('')`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqRecord.SeqRecord-class.html#format) returns the record as a `string`.

[`.encode()`](http://pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/) converts the `string` to a `byte` object.